# Is there a class like flash/openfl DisplayObjectCointainer in HaxeFlixel?

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel

Something like that which holds FlxBasic, FlxObject members, position and total size so I could group them and set their position as a group with ease.

I don't need other alternative class in another library. I can write a simple class like that. But I just ask so as to not waste my time writing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing like that for `FlxBasic` or `FlxObject`, just for `FlxSprite` (which is one further down the inheritance chain). There are two options:

- `FlxSpriteGroup`: part of core flixel, basically a `FlxSprite` with a `FlxGroup` that can hold additional sprites and manipulates the properties of those sprites as well - this means stuff like rotation and scaling works on each individual sprite, as opposed to the group acting as a single rotated / scaled sprite.
- `FlxNestedSprite`: part of flixel-addons (and perhaps not as well maintained as a result), pretty much an imitation of a `DisplayObjectContainer`.